# Passing data between processes using named pipe

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to pass data between c# (winforms) program using a c++ (win32) program (both programs are local).

The flow is that the c++ program spawns the winform (via `CreateProcess()`), and then continues to send data via the pipe continuously to the spawned program.

Following this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561604/create-named-pipe-c-windows), I am able to create a pipe on the win32 program, however I have no idea on how to capture the information transmitted by the pipe within the .NET framework.

Can someone point me to an example on how to do it?

Comment: `NamedPipeClientStream` class can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740479/two-way-c-to-c-sharp-communication-using-named-pipes